# PermissionError (WinError 31) A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: python, pip, windows-8.1

I am trying to install pip by `python get-pip.py` command on my python3.6 virtualenv but i get the error:

```
(myvenv_python3) C:\Users\Kaleab\Downloads>python get-pip.py --trusted-host=pypi
.org
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b
44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 31] A device at
tached to the system is not functioning
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-
8'>
PermissionError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functionin
g

(myvenv_python3) C:\Users\Kaleab\Downloads>
```

What solution would you recommend? I am using Windows 8.1 machine.

Answer (score 8):

I am on Windows 7. I came across the same bug.
I read the [discussion here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5878). It seems to be caused by UTF-8 support if you have English Windows.

Just type:

```
chcp 1252
```

then run your pip again.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the PermissionError was because i changed registry code page to 65001:
`REG ADD HKCU\Console /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /d 65001 /f`
So, remove the autorun registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor. If you want to use utf-8 ( 65001) just use `chcp 65001` on command prompt.