# python pip install gives EnvironmentError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to install the telethon package. It installs ok on my current version (3.5.1), but gives a syntax error upon importing it which i believe is due to my python version being too low, so i installed python 3.7.0. When i try to install the package using  i get the error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functioning
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
PermissionError: [WinError 31] A device attached to the system is not functioning
```

Using --user doesn't help, and i also tried uninstalling 3.7.0 and installing 3.6.6 instead but get the same error. This error also happens when i try to install other packages, like pipenv. Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: [maybe this question will be helpful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50085366/permissionerror-winerror-31-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning)

Comment: I haven't touched the registry